# Creating vector<thread>

Tags: c++

I am simply trying to create a `std::vector` of threads and run them.

Code:

```
thread t1(calc, 95648, "t1");
thread t2(calc, 54787, "t2");
thread t3(calc, 42018, "t3");
thread t4(calc, 75895, "t4");
thread t5(calc, 81548, "t5");

vector<thread> threads { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 };
```

Error: "function std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)" (declared at line 70 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\thread") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

```
thread(const thread&) = delete;
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since threads aren't copyable, but movable, I recommend the following approach:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

threads.emplace_back(calc, 95648, "t1");
threads.emplace_back(calc, 54787, "t2");
threads.emplace_back(calc, 42018, "t3");
threads.emplace_back(calc, 75895, "t4");
threads.emplace_back(calc, 81548, "t5");
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Can you explain me why my code didn't work and what yours does?

Comment: Because `thread` object cannot be copied (when you insert a value into a vector, it is copied), but with `emplace`, it is created directly in-place in the vector itself.

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
vector<thread> threads 
{ 
    std::move(t1),
    std::move(t2),
    std::move(t3),
    std::move(t4),
    std::move(t5) 
};
```

Comment: Correct - the copy constructor is deleted (what would it mean to copy a thread?) but moving one is allowed.

Comment: after doing that i get the following error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(593): error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: Did C++ magically invent movable-from initializer lists? What year is it, 2038?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Just removed the erroneous solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copying of `thread` objects is forbidden. Moving is allowed. But you can use a `shared_ptr` to solve this.

My favorite way to use vectors of threads is via shared pointer.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
```

Using them in this way lets always enough flexibility to extend the vector (vectors are used to be extensible).

```
threads.push_back(std::shared_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(&some_fn)));
```

For your code this would look like:

```
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<thread> t1 = make_shared<thread>(calc, 95648, "t1");
shared_ptr<thread> t2 = make_shared<thread>(calc, 54787, "t2");
shared_ptr<thread> t3 = make_shared<thread>(calc, 42018, "t3");
shared_ptr<thread> t4 = make_shared<thread>(calc, 75895, "t4");
shared_ptr<thread> t5 = make_shared<thread>(calc, 81548, "t5");

vector<shared_ptr<thread>> threads { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 };
```

Comment: I would call this misuse of shared_ptr. There is no shared ownership involved here.

Comment: It is possible, that someone asks for a reference of that thread (e.g. thread pooling). This is not specified in the question. Then it would be a problem, if you give a c reference, that could fail if not needed immediately. For me this often eases the pain of dealing with legacy code in large frameworks.