# Matlab Engine closes unexpectedly after thread ends in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab

**Updated**

(Because my original condition is no longer appropriate after several tests, I changed the code example to better describe the problem)

Long story short, the Matlab engine opened in the thread in my C++ application closed unexpectedly after the thread ends without calling `engClose()` explicitly. I hope anyone can help me solve the mystery and find a way to better control the engine.

The detail described as follows

I know that Matlab Engine API is not thread-safe. But for windows, I figure that with `engOpenSingleUse()`, multi-threaded may still be achievable. The idea here was to have the calculations from different objects (classes) operate on the same Matlab computational engine while they were in the same thread. Each thread then accesses its own interface which contains a valid Matlab engine pointer among those objects. and therefore, avoid conflict in my multi-thread application. Then I bumped in to this issue. The Mmatlab Engine closed itself after the thread ended, without calling `engClose()`.

For testing purpose, I would want those Matlab engines remain open so I can perform additional checks and operations by entering code directly in the consoles.

After many tests, I finally realized that it's not about how I implement the Matlab engine because simply calling `engOpen()` or `engOpenSingleUse()` in thread would result in this issue.

Here is an example I use for test

```
#include<memory>
#include<thread>
#include<map>
#include<engine.h>

void callback() {
    Engine* ep = engOpenSingleUse(NULL,NULL,NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> thread1;
    thread1 = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&callback);
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> thread2;
    thread2 = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&callback);    
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    return 1;
}
```

The code compiled and ran fine. Two instances of Matlab engines started and ran as expected. But somehow the Matlab engine I started along the thread closed itself without calling `engClose();`.

If I didn't call the `callback()` using the `thread`, e.g.

```
void main() {callback();}
```

the application ends with an opened Matlab engine, which is totally expected. But using the thread, all Matlab engines closed automatically.

Have anyone even encountered similar problem? I would like those instances remain open unless I instruct the close signal explicitly, otherwise I could lose control in my management class because the engine closes unexpectedly. Any thought is appreciated.

**Edit**

As a comment pointed, I don't need `shared_ptr` in this case. But the truth is that it is somehow necessary in my real implementation. The simple example here may seem to be unnecessary,though. Anyhow, in case you wonder, I did try

```
std::thread thread1(callback);
std::thread thread2(callback);
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

The result is complete the same. So using the pointer or not is definitely not the issue here.

Comment: Can't help with the crux of your problem, but there is little harm in, and absolutely no reason for, `shared_ptr` on those threads. No one is sharing them. Their lifespan is entirely within `main`, so there's no need for them to be pointers at all. `std::thread> _thread1(&callback);` should do it for you. Also recommend a read of [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Doesn't look like you're breaking any here, but...

Comment: @user4581301 But..? Thanks for your comment but the link is not helpful to my question. This was just a simplified example, part of a grant project. The use of shared_ptr is due to this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/24448649/2363688. In fact, I tried use without pointer and the result is the same.

Comment: Only bit in there that will be helpful to your current problem is you can lose the shared pointers and go with Automatic variables. Worth doing to eliminate the added complexity they bring.

Comment: Watch out for the underscore thing, though. The only way you're likely to know you've messed it up is after you've spent hours or days hunting a bizarro mystery bug.